# php count same data in database

Tags: php, database

my database:

```
| order_detail_id | order_id | product_id | product_name 
|       1         |    1     |      20    | Polygon Fg56 
|       2         |    2     |      20    | Polygon Fg56 
|       3         |    2     |      20    | Polygon Fg56 
|       4         |    3     |      14    | fixie 11
```

I've been able to select the table, but I want to calculate how much data has the same value in the product_name column, for example to Polygon Fg56 have 3 record, and fixie 11 have 1 record. how?

Comment: basic question easily searchable through google, no efforts shown whatsoever. -1

Comment: My answer below will do what you need but you should really look into normalising the data. Ie. moving the product id and name into a products table and joining the orders onto it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    `t`.`product_name`,
    count(`t`.`order_detail_id`) as `count`
from `table` as `t`
group by `t`.`product_name`
```

Comment: add the product name to the select, otherwise it's quite useless as a query :)

Comment: Very true, made the changes

Comment: but i want get the name too, example Polygon Fg56 [3 record]
if i select like that, it's only return integer

Comment: The edited example above will give you that

Comment: finnaly i got it, just add product_name in select, sorry. thank bro

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT `product_name `, COUNT(`product_name `) AS cnt FROM `table` GROUP BY `product_name `;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_name,count(product_name)
from table
group by product_name
```

Here you will get how many records are there for each product( you will also get that product name)